# Ruby On Rails - Rails generate migration doesn't generate migration file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I am trying to generate some migration files but the following command :

```
rails generate migration create_users
```

doesn't generate any migration file.

Also, there is an empty output rather than some text containing the file name and other details...

Do I need to have a special gem? I am using `sqlite` gem for db.

Comment: It should generate the migration file. What is the output when you run that command?

Comment: There is no output when running the command

Comment: That should just work, you shoudn't need any extra gems. Is it fresh rails app?

Comment: Is it because I am using rails 3?

Comment: What version of rails/ruby ?

Comment: Rails v3.2.22 & ruby v2.2.2p95

Comment: try `ruby script/generate migration create_users`

Comment: did you run `bundle update`?